# What do the blue/purple item prices mean?

Tags: smite

I've been playing Smite since they first started (/brag) and I still don't know why some items have blue or purple price tags. They seem to be discounted, but the reason eludes me. What does a colored item price mean, and what triggers them?

## Edit

Here's why I was confused. When you first look at an item, it shows how much it will cost to upgrade the item *completely* from tier 1 to 3:

[image: 1]

When you buy tier 1, it *still* shows the total cost to upgrade from tier 2 to 3:

[image: 2]

Because you already spent 1010 gold on tier 1, the cost for tier 2 and 3 are reduced by 1010. This could be confusing to noobs (like me) who thought that the prices reflected the cost for only that tier.

Comment: As the game updated to use a [item tree system](http://www.funnel.asia/news/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Auto-purchase-buton-SMITE.jpg) this question is no longer valid at all and should maybe be deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The different color price is basically a separator, if they were all yellow it would seem a little bit odd.

The start of a game is a perfect example to give, in Assault Mode you have enough gold at the start to fully complete an item, would you rather those 3 prices be yellow? Or the colors they are now to signify upgrades?

Comment: Are you sure of this? Even when there's just 1 upgrade left (tier 3) and no other prices are shown, it's occasionally purple, blue or white. I'll have to double check that, but I'm fairly sure it varies.